# detect if string contains only comma, then remove the comma php

Tags: php

First I have a dynamic string like this

> ,

and sometimes like this

> firstname,

and sometimes like this too

> , lastname

how can I detect like if string contains only comma then make the string empty (remove the comma) else if string contains firstname and comma (no lastname, see format below)

> firstname,

then remove the comma inside the string and keep the firstname else if the string contains comma and lastname then remove the comma as well and keep the lastname inside the string.

any ideas, help, clues, suggestions, recommendations to achieve that please?

Comment: maybe `$string = trim($string, ',');` should do.

Comment: $str = str_replace(",", "", $str);

Comment: **Preg_replace** is also an option

Comment: so basically always remove the comma? You couldn't think of a more complicated way to word that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all occurrences of a string from within a string with str_replace, which will work even if the comma is in the middle of the string.

```
//Here we are replacing all occurrences of "," with "" inside $string
$string = str_replace(",", "", $string);
```

If you just want to remove the commas from the left / right, then trim() is the way to go, as follows:

```
$string = trim($string, ",");
```

Sources:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Hope I was helpful!

Comment: wil, the string is dynamic, so first I have to detect from above scenario.

Comment: If it is dynamic and you want to remove ALL of the commas, then use str_replace.

Answer (score 2):

If your comma is only at the beginning and at the end of your string you could do that:

```
$firstname = rtrim('firstname', ',');
$lastname = ltrim(', lastname', ', ');
```

Check out [ltrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) and [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
  <?php     

      $name = 'Firstname,';   // If you give value "," you will get blank

      $filename_withou_comma = explode (',',$name);
      echo $filename_withou_comma[0];
      echo $filename_withou_comma[1];

      ?>
```

Comment: wil, the string is dynamic, so first I have to detect from above scenario.

Comment: Yes you can use dynamic string that you may call from database or POST or GET, for example.

<?php $name = $_POST['field_name']; ?>